# Corruption in C++ constructor

Tags: c++, gcc, stl

I'm facing corruption in constructor . Can someone help me ?

```
    2873            int rc = _db->fetch_custom_sql_query(rwc.GetQueryName(),selectConstruct, HandleCustomSqlQueryResponse, (void*)&holder);
    (gdb) p selectConstruct
    $1 = {distinct = false, colsToBeSelected = {cols = {<std::_Vector_base<dbCol,     std::allocator<dbCol> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<dbCol>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<dbCol>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0}}, <No data fields>}}, tableName = {static npos = 18446744073709551615, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x3dd36f32d8 ""}}, where = {whereExprs = {<std::_Vector_base<whereExpr, std::allocator<whereExpr> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<whereExpr>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<whereExpr>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0}}, <No data fields>}, ops = {<std::_Vector_base<adjoinOperator, std::allocator<adjoinOperator> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<adjoinOperator>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<adjoinOperator>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0}}, <No data fields>}, namespaceCounts = {<std::_Vector_base<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<unsigned int>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<unsigned int>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0}}, <No data fields>}, useAsON = false}, groupBy = {cols = {<std::_Vector_base<dbCol, std::allocator<dbCol> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<dbCol>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<dbCol>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0}}, <No data fields>}}, orders = {orders = {<std::_Vector_base<orderingTerm, std::allocator<orderingTerm> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<orderingTerm>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<orderingTerm>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0}}, <No data fields>}}, limit = -1}
   (gdb) stepi
    0x00007ffff0df9b49      2873            int rc = _db-   >fetch_custom_sql_query(rwc.GetQueryName(),selectConstruct, HandleCustomSqlQueryResponse, (void*)&holder);
   (gdb) stepi
   0x00007ffff0df9b50      2873            int rc = _db->fetch_custom_sql_query(rwc.GetQueryName(),selectConstruct, HandleCustomSqlQueryResponse, (void*)&holder);
   (gdb) stepi
   0x00007ffff0df9b53      2873            int rc = _db->fetch_custom_sql_query(rwc.GetQueryName(),selectConstruct, HandleCustomSqlQueryResponse, (void*)&holder);
  (gdb) stepi
   0x00007ffff0df9b5b      2873            int rc = _db->fetch_custom_sql_query(rwc.GetQueryName(),selectConstruct, HandleCustomSqlQueryResponse, (void*)&holder);
   (gdb) stepi
   0x00007ffff0df9b5e      2873            int rc = _db->fetch_custom_sql_query(rwc.GetQueryName(),selectConstruct, HandleCustomSqlQueryResponse, (void*)&holder);
   (gdb) stepi
    0x00007ffff0da8000 in simpleSelectConstruct::simpleSelectConstruct () from   /opt/OV/lbin/OpsAgt/libDMLSegment.so
   (gdb) stepi
   simpleSelectConstruct::simpleSelectConstruct (this=0x7fffdbffdbb0) at /home/parakkal/COLLABNET_11.10_NEW/hpsw-oa/AgentFramework/cpp/src/include/OpsAgt/DBsupports.h:170
   170     class simpleSelectConstruct{
   /include/OpsAgt/DBsupports.h:170
   170     class simpleSelectConstruct{
  (gdb) p *this
   $2 = {distinct = false, colsToBeSelected = {cols = {<std::_Vector_base<dbCol,   std::allocator<dbCol> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<dbCol>> =  {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<dbCol>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0}}, <No data fields>}}, tableName = {static npos = 18446744073709551615, _M_dataplus = {<std::allocator<char>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_p = 0x0}}, where = {whereExprs = {<std::_Vector_base<whereExpr, std::allocator<whereExpr> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<whereExpr>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<whereExpr>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0}}, <No data fields>}, ops = {<std::_Vector_base<adjoinOperator, std::allocator<adjoinOperator> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<adjoinOperator>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<adjoinOperator>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x3dd34bd704, _M_end_of_storage = 0x7ffff7ca52b0}}, <No data fields>}, namespaceCounts = {<std::_Vector_base<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<unsigned int>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<unsigned int>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x7fffdbffe910, _M_finish = 0x6, _M_end_of_storage = 0x4e}}, <No data fields>}, useAsON = false}, groupBy = {cols = {<std::_Vector_base<dbCol, std::allocator<dbCol> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<dbCol>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<dbCol>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x7fffdbffe910, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x7ffff6f54d1f}}, <No data fields>}}, orders = {orders = {<std::_Vector_base<orderingTerm, std::allocator<orderingTerm> >> = {_M_impl = {<std::allocator<orderingTerm>> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator<orderingTerm>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, _M_start = 0x7ffff7ca52b0, _M_finish = 0x7ffff6f5584d, _M_end_of_storage = 0x5509f0}}, <No data fields>}}, limit = -603988688}
  (gdb) stepi
```

If you see above limit is corrupted in the constructor , so is _M_start , _M_finish and _M_end_of_storage.  The `simpleSelectConstruct` class is shown here

```
class simpleSelectConstruct{

 public:
   DBSupportsInterface simpleSelectConstruct()
   {
      distinct=false;
      limit=-1;
   }
   bool distinct;
   dbCols colsToBeSelected;
   string tableName;
   whereConstruct where;
   dbCols groupBy;
   orderBy orders;
   int limit;
};
```

I've posted the complete info at 
https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2014-08/msg00104.html

Comment: Looks like an encryption to me. My instructor used to do this with code he would give us so we could see what the final program should look like, without giving us the code, for tests and stuff

Comment: @NavinParakkal: Though the constructor is the _direct_ cause of the observed corruption, the constructor is not the issue.  The issue is (A) something is calling the constructor where it ought not be, or (B) the stack has become corrupted, causing the constructor to be called both when and where it ought not be.  In either case, I can't help without a lot more details, because I don't understand that gdb output.  I hope someone with more knowledge about this shows up :(

Comment: Dumping your entire code (not even properly aligned) somewhere and posting a link to it doesn't look like a serious effort of analyzing the problem before posting it here. Find the relevant piece of code which causes the problem, and publish it **here** (what you've published on that link doesn't even have an entry-point in the form of a `main` function, for example, so how do you expect anyone to be able to investigate it?).

Comment: Additionally, I see no evidence of corruption.  I see that you print out a non-corrupted variable `selectConstruct`, step into the `simpleSelectConstruct` constructor, print the `simpleSelectConstruct` that's about to be constructed, make four steps, and then print the `simpleSelectConstruct` that is only half constructed.  (Neither of which is the `selectConstruct` variable).  Then you complain that it's not fully constructed.  Did you try waiting until after the constructor completed?

Comment: It appears to have initialized `distinct, colsToBeSelected, tableName`, but not yet initialized `where, groupBy, orders, limit`.

Comment: In C++, objects with proper constructors are initialized before constructor body (so you'd use initializer list if you want to pass parameters). Plain data classes (no constructors doing anything) and primitive types are left with uninitialized values at this stage of construction. Maybe you are seeing this?

Comment: @hyde: You may be right.  I can't tell if `distinct` is initialized or not since it starts as `false` and ends as `false`, but `colsToBeSelected` and `tablename` are _clearly_ initialized, wheras `groupBy` and `limit` are _clearly_ not.  (I didn't examine `orders`.)  In any case, the solution appears to be to wait for the constructor to complete.  Actually, wait, the C++ spec says that members are constructed in the order they're declared! (though there's the as-if rule still)

Comment: @hyde Upon further review, I misread, no members are clearly initialized, I was accidentally looking at the `selectConstruct` variable

Answer (score 1):

```
(gdb) stepi
0x00007ffff0df9b5e      2873            int rc =
_db->fetch_custom_sql_query(rwc.GetQueryName(),selectConstruct,HandleCustomSqlQueryResponse, (void*)&holder);
(gdb) stepi
0x00007ffff0da8000 in simpleSelectConstruct::simpleSelectConstruct ()
from /opt/OV/lbin/OpsAgt/libDMLSegment.so
(gdb) stepi
simpleSelectConstruct::simpleSelectConstruct (this=0x7fffdbffdbb0) 
[SNIP]
(gdb) p *this
[SNIP OUTPUT BEFORE CONSTRUCTOR RUNS]
(gdb) stepi
0x00007ffff0e11892      170     class simpleSelectConstruct{
(gdb) stepi
0x00007ffff0e11894      170     class simpleSelectConstruct{
(gdb) stepi
0x00007ffff0e11896      170     class simpleSelectConstruct{
(gdb) stepi
0x00007ffff0e11898      170     class simpleSelectConstruct{
(gdb) p *this
[SNIP OUTPUT DURING CONSTRUCTOR]
(gdb)
[END OF DEBUGGING SESSION]
```

I see no evidence of corruption. I see that you print out a non-corrupted variable selectConstruct, step into the `simpleSelectConstruct` constructor, print the `simpleSelectConstruct` that's about to be constructed, make four steps, and then print the `simpleSelectConstruct` that is only half constructed. (Neither of which is the `selectConstruct` variable). Did you try waiting until after the constructor completed?

When constructor begins:

```
distinct = false
colsToBeSelected = 
    cols = ..._M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0 ...
tableName = ..._M_p = 0x0 ...
where = 
    whereExprs = ..._M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0...
    ops = ..._M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x3dd34bd704, _M_end_of_storage = 0x7ffff7ca52b0...
    namespaceCounts = ..._M_start = 0x7fffdbffe910, _M_finish = 0x6, _M_end_of_storage = 0x4e...
    useAsON = false
groupBy = 
    cols = ..._M_start = 0x7fffdbffe910, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x7ffff6f54d1f...
orders = ..._M_start = 0x7ffff7ca52b0, _M_finish = 0x7ffff6f5584d, _M_end_of_storage = 0x5509f0...
limit = -603988688
```

After four steps in the constructor:

```
distinct = false
colsToBeSelected = 
    cols = ..._M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0 ...
tableName = ..._M_p = 0x0...
where = 
    whereExprs = ..._M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x0...
    ops = ..._M_start = 0x0, _M_finish = 0x3dd34bd704, _M_end_of_storage = 0x7ffff7ca52b0...
    namespaceCounts = ..._M_start = 0x7fffdbffe910, _M_finish = 0x6, _M_end_of_storage = 0x4e...
    useAsON = false
groupBy = 
    cols = ..._M_start = 0x7fffdbffe910, _M_finish = 0x0, _M_end_of_storage = 0x7ffff6f54d1f...
orders = ..._M_start = 0x7ffff7ca52b0, _M_finish = 0x7ffff6f5584d, _M_end_of_storage = 0x5509f0...
limit = -603988688
```

The constructor clearly hasn't finished executing yet.  It appears to be pretty early in the construction process still.  I would assume that the four operations are assinging false, and then `cols`, so the next step would be to construct `tableName`.